# How can I detect how many levels down Pry has gone

Tags: ruby, pry

If I'm at a Bash prompt and I type `bash` I can then detect that I'm at the 2nd level by typing `echo $SHLVL`.

Suppose I'm in a pry session and I type `pry` again.  How can I detect that I'm at the 2nd level down? How can I detect the Pry level? Nothing listed in `(Pry.methods - Object.methods).sort`  seems to have anything useful.

This is for testing some code for a pry-related project, where I need detect the level.

Answer (score 0):

If you call `caller` within a pry session within a pry session, then you will see a list of commands. Among them, you should be able to find the part that corresponds to a nested `pry` call. Find the crucial line that is related to each pry session call, and you will know your level. As far as I checked, you should find two occurrences of a line like:

```
 "/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:67:in `repl'"
```

Count such lines.